# How to add CMS Static block above product Description Section

Tags: magento2.3.4, cms-block, product-description

I want to add cms block above description, how to do in custom theme?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in your **catalog_product_view.xml** file,

```
    <referenceContainer name="content"> 
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="demo" before="product.info.details"> 
                <arguments> 
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">demo</argument> 
                </arguments> 
            </block> 
     </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: I i did, its not applied, i am created cms static block id= "1", identifier= "demo" just put into your script, its not working.

Comment: instead of "block_identifier" use your block identifier.

Comment: I am getting following error, 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'name': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'block identifier' is not accepted by the pattern '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z\d-_.]*'.
Line: 1195

Comment: please share your code..

Comment: <referenceContainer name="content">
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block identifier" before="product.info.details">
<arguments>
<argument name="1" xsi:type="string">demo</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceContainer>

Comment: Answer is updated and also do not use the block id instead of "block_id" in argument just put the my updated answer in your file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118368/discussion-between-zus-and-madani).